# KeyError: 'the label [-2] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

indexing the dataframe as df[*'column_name'*].iloc[-1] when printing on line 10 to 13, works and prints the value at that position.

but then when I use the same syntax in a condition block, it throws an error.

What am I doing wrong ?

```py
import pandas

def job():
        # get the dataframe
        df = pandas.read_csv('stock_prices.csv')

        # change dataframe column types datatypes
        df = df.astype({'close': 'float64', 'high': 'float64', 'low': 'float64', 'open': 'float64', 'timestamp': 'int64', 'volume': 'int64'})

        print('last close price :', df['close'].iloc[-1])
        print('2nd last close price :', df['close'].iloc[-2])
        print('last open price :', df['open'].iloc[-1])
        print('2nd last open price :', df['open'].iloc[-2])


        if df['open'].iloc[-2] < df['open'].iloc[-1]:
            if df['close'].iloc[-2] < df['close'].iloc[-2]:
                print('its time to buy')
                return


        if df['open'].loc[-2] > df['open'].loc[-1]:
            if df['close'].loc[-2] > df['close'].iloc[-1]:
                print('its time to sell')
                return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    job()
```

The output is as follows

```
last close price : 588.5
2nd last close price : 587.3
last open price : 587.25
2nd last open price : 586.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1506, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [-2] is not in the [index]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\Desktop\for_stack.py", line 28, in <module>
    job()
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\Desktop\for_stack.py", line 22, in job
    if df['open'].loc[-2] > df['open'].loc[-1]:
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1373, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1626, in _getitem_axis
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1514, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "C:\Users\Whistler.81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [-2] is not in the [index]'
[Finished in 1.9s]
```

Comment: You said `.loc` instead of `.iloc` at line `if df['open'].loc[-2] > df['open'].loc[-1]`. And the line below, the first is `.loc` and the second is correct with `.iloc` --- Advice : You should store the data, and apply comparisons on it, instead of accessing it everytime you make a comparison.

Comment: thanks for your reply, you mean, close_previous =df['close'].iloc[-2], close_next = df['close'].iloc[-1] and so on ?

Comment: You nicely used `.iloc` on the beginning of your script. I assume it is what you wanted to do. :) So yeah, replace your `.loc` by `.iloc`

Comment: @IMCoins i cannot thank you enough for spotting the missing 'i's.